# How to stop build of nuget package if it has references to dev/beta packages in TeamCity?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget, teamcity

I am using Git and would like it when I merge to my master branch it would automatically stop the process in TeamCity if my nuget-package had references to other dev/beta packages. This way I can be sure that my releases always references other release packages and no pre-releases.

Is there a way to solve this using MSBuild, Nuget or TeamCity?

**EDIT:**

As I understand it, this does not work out of the box using MSBuild or Nuget. Is it a good way to make a pre-build step for TeamCity that checks if the projects have pre-release references?

Answer (score 0):

In the release branch of the solution that references these packages you have to restrict references to be non-pre-release only and run update references.

You can rebase the dev branch to this later on when you merge release to dev and master, then dev could deviate by using pre-release packages again.

There is nothing special required from your CI server or Nuget to support this.

But there is no real way to **stop** the build, unless you create a special tool that will check versions in package.config files. You can separate feeds for release and pre-release packages and limit the restore to release only feed during the build but nuget will scan **all** configurations and eventually will find both feeds. The only solution that I know is to use **[paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/)** instead of Nuget. Paket allows you to specify feed configuration per solution. It also gives you clear indicator on which versions you have referenced and any pre-release restrictions. It also prevents you from having multiple version of the same package for different projects in one solution.

When using **paket**, you could check the `paket.lock` file for any occurrences of `-unstable` in it (assuming you follow SemVer for your packages). like this:

```
$ findstr "-unstable" paket.lock
```

Comment: How do I restrict the references to be non-pre-release only? To clearify, I do want my build to stop if I have a reference to a pre-release. This way we have control on the versions we are releasing.

Comment: When you not specifically instructs nuget to use pre-release, it will use release versions only:
Upgrading Prerelease Packages

The Update-Package command will update all packages to the latest stable version. As before, use the -IncludePrerelease flag to upgrade to the latest stable or prelease package, whichever is latest.

Comment: That will not solve my initial problem as mention in my question :-(

Comment: As I wrote, there is no way to **stop** the build in such situation, unless you write your own tool. But creating release branches is not done chaotic, someone must control the process and have some sort of a flow. This flow might as well have a step to run package update. Some things just don't need to be automated.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have edited my question to be more precise.

Comment: I know both TeamCity and NuGet quite well and I am 95% sure it does not have the feature you are asking about. I updated my answer with a possible solution.